# ZorinOS, based on Ubuntu 20.04, stuck on the Zorin splash screen

Tags: boot, gnome, gdm, zorin

New to Linux. Will try to keep this concise.

After using Zorin today, I accidentally hit the logout button, and it dropped me into the tty. But before the tty became interactable, i.e, before I could start typing in it, it hanged on me. I hit the power button and forcefully closed the laptop, then tried to boot into Zorin again, but then it just kept getting stuck at the Zorin splash screen.

Tried to do the following -

Went into the terminal as root through recovery mode, and checked the status of gdm. Started gdm, and then on checking the status, it said gdm active, but it also said gdm couldn’t access dkms. Tried installing/updating dkms, to no avail.
Configuration/specifications -

1. Kernel : 5.8.0-53 generic
2. Architecture : x86_64
3. ZorinOS : based on Ubuntu 20.04
4. Hybrid graphics :

   - Dedicated - Nvidia GTX 1650, Driver version - 460.73.01
   - Integrated - Intel UHD 630
5. Display manager : gdm
6. Dekstop Enviroment : Gnome
7. Is dual booted with Windows 10

Comment: sounds like you misconfigured your graphics driver. maybe you start with uninstalling NVIDIA drivers, to get back your graphical environment. This you can also do without recovery mode. When you stuck in boot, hit F1 and your should see last massages. With Alt+F1 to Alt+F12 you can change to a logon shell.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the advice. I started with uninstalling dkms which also got rid of the drivers, and then i was able to successfully boot in. Now i'm just setting up the drivers again properly :)

Comment: It seems to be a driver problem with Ubuntu/Zorin. Nouveau works but is slow as hell. Thanks for the help.